# How do I randomly select 'k' positions in a list and shuffle their respective elements without effecting the other elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Imagine I have some list:

```
listA = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};
```

I'd like to randomly select `k` positions in the list, for example `k = 3` and we select positions `{1,9,10}`, then randomly shuffle the elements at these positions e.g. giving us ONE of the following five possible outcomes:

```
listApartialscramble1 = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};
listApartialscramble1 = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j","i"};
listApartialscramble2 = {"i","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j","a"};
listApartialscramble3 = {"i","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","a","j"};
listApartialscramble4 = {"j","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a"};
listApartialscramble5 = {"j","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","a","i"};
```

Is there a simple way to do this, perhaps with `RandomSample`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
listA=CharacterRange["a","j"];

k = 5;
set = RandomSample[Range@Length@listA, k]

listA[[ set]] = listA[[ RandomSample@set]];
listA
```

> ```
> {8, 3, 10, 1, 4}
> {"g", "b", "c", "d", "j", "f", "e", "h", "i", "a"}
> ```

Comment: Funny, I've always written this operation `listA[[set]] = RandomSample @ listA[[set]]` -- it never occurred to me to shuffle the indices though the effect is equivalent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard :) I'm probably biased by the question wording where positions/indices are stressed. That being said, I don't know now if I'd use your approach but yes, I haven't thought about it :)