# Randomly selecting and reinserting a subset of elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, random

This question is similar to my other question: [How do I randomly select 'k' positions in a list and shuffle their respective elements without effecting the other elements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46149/how-do-i-randomly-select-k-positions-in-a-list-and-shuffle-their-respective-el)

Imagine first a pack of cards.  We randomly draw $k$ cards from the pack, and then sequentially reinsert them 'somewhere' in the deck (between cards or above or below the deck).  Now I'd like to do the same thing with list elements using some hypothetical function `pluckReinsert`:

```
 k = 3;
 list = {card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, ..., cardN}
 pluckReinsert[list,k]

 output > {card2, card1, card3, card7, card4, card5, card42, card6, card8, ...}
```

Here, by chance, we randomly chose to "pluck" the set of cards: `{card2, card7, card42}`.  We then, sequentially, placed `card2` on top of card 1 (there were $N+1$ total choices given the $N$ cards in the deck), placed `card7` between `card3` and `card4`, and finally, placed `card42` between `card5` and `card6`.  At any of these sequential addition steps, there are were $N+1$ choices for placing the card (i.e. there would be nothing to stop us from an ordering like: `{card42, card2, card1, card3, card4, card5, card6, card8, ..., cardN, card7}`).

Is there a clever Mathematica trick to do this in one or two lines?

Comment: I have 12 lines. That's a 1 and a 2..

Comment: Yes. In fact, I'm pretty sure with the undocumented `Developer``DemiCompile` it can be done in half a line.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe longer than 1 or 2 lines but it is readable. Of course you could shorten it, but I tend to mess up the code when I try to make it too short. :-)

```
newStack[list_, k_] := 
      Module[{smallerStack, drawnCards, randomChoice, length},
      length = Length[list];
      randomChoice = RandomSample[Range[length], k];
      drawnCards = list[[randomChoice]] /. colorBefore -> colorAfter;
      smallerStack = Delete[list, Partition[randomChoice, 1]];
      Do[smallerStack = Insert[smallerStack, drawnCards[[i]],    RandomInteger[{1, Length[smallerStack]}]], {i, 1, Length[drawnCards]}];
      smallerStack
];
```

Works nicely:

```
NN = 10;
colorBefore = Green;
colorAfter = Orange;
stack = Table[Framed[IntegerString[i, 10, Ceiling[Log[10, NN]] + 1], Background -> colorBefore], {i, 1, NN}];
newStack[stack, 3]
```

gives e.g.

[image]

You can also use real symbols of cards as they are discussed here: [Standard deck of 52 playing cards in curated data?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2qDj.png)

```
 coolCards = Flatten[ImagePartition[Import["http://www.milefoot.com/math/discrete/counting/images/cards.png"], {73, 98}], 1];
```

To show the effect on the cards I use the effect to invert the images object in the given list that were shuffled:

```
newStackImage[list_, k_] := Module[{smallerStack, drawnCards, randomChoice, length, full},
    length = Length[list];
    randomChoice = RandomSample[Range[length], k];
    drawnCards = ColorNegate[#] & /@ list[[randomChoice]];
    smallerStack = Delete[list, Partition[randomChoice, 1]];
    Do[smallerStack = 
     Insert[smallerStack, drawnCards[[i]], RandomInteger[{1, Length[smallerStack]+1}]], {i, 1, Length[drawnCards]}];
    smallerStack
];
```

When applying this function to the full set of cards

```
newStackImage[coolCards, 3]
```

we obtain:

[image]

Was it important to have it in 1 or 2 lines? :-) Its easy to compress the code but will be less readable

Of course it works with duplicate entries in the list as well.

Remark: an earlier Version of this answer included an answer how to take three cards that follow each other and put them alltogether back in some place of the remaining deck. You can find this answer in the edit history.

Comment: I don't think this is addressing the problem as originally posed. In particular neither the selected elements, nor the insertion positions, need be contiguous.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will work it out.

Comment: nit picking i think you need to add 1 to the random range or you'll never insert at the end

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain I understand the question so I'll post my code and you can tell me if this does what you expect:

```
pluck[cards_, n_] := {cards[[#]], Delete[cards, List /@ #]} & @ 
  RandomSample[Range @ Length @ cards, n]

place[{set_, cards_}] :=
  Fold[Insert[#, #2, 1 + RandomInteger @ Length @ #] &, cards, set]
```

Example:

```
Array[C, 10] ~pluck~ 3 // place
```

> ```
> {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[7], C[9], C[4], C[5], C[10], C[6], C[8]}
> ```

---

#### Optimization

Looking at this problem again, and again inspired by an answer from rasher[<sup>(1)</sup>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/121), I *think* an equivalent `place` operation can be done as follows:

```
place2[{set_, cards_}] :=
  Join[ConstantArray[0, Length @ cards], Range @ Length @ set] //
    Join[cards, set][[ Nest[Ordering, RandomSample @ #, 2] ]] &
```

On small lists this is only moderately faster, but on long lists it is *much* faster:

```
dat = pluck[Range[52], 52];

Do[place[dat], {50000}]  // Timing // First
Do[place2[dat], {50000}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.716
>
> 0.437
> ```

```
dat = pluck[Range[1*^6], 1*^4];

dat // place  // Timing // First
dat // place2 // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 13.416
>
> 0.0874
> ```

Comment: So it looks like the first line randomly samples three elements from the list (i.e. cards from the deck) and then deletes these elements in the list (removes these cards in the deck).  The second line then places these elements (cards), sequentially into the list at the list' front / back / or between any elements (cards).  Is this a correct interpretation for your code?  If so, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: This generally allows for and retains duplicate elements in the list (cards in the deck) right?  It isn't totally necessary, but its nice that this is general.

Comment: @S22 Yes, and yes.  If your "deck" is not long this code is probably all you need.  If you are dealing with very long lists (hundreds of thousands of elements) it will become slow because every `Insert` takes time proportional to the length of the list into which it is inserting.  (See [this related Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/121)). rasher seems to have a way around this but I haven't examined it yet.

Comment: @S22 Actually rasher's second method does not appear to have equivalent probability to this algorithm.

Comment: I think your algorithm works well for my purposes, and is quite nice.  However, if it's ok, I'm going to wait a little bit to accept since I'm actually learning a huge amount from the postings here!

Answer (score 2):

As with Mr.W, not *totally* clear on the question, but I *think* this does what you want:

```
pluckReinsert[list_, num_] := 
 Module[{picked, left}, 
  Fold[Insert[#, #2, RandomInteger[{1, Length@# + 1}]] &, 
   Sequence @@ 
    With[{picked = RandomSample[list, num]}, {left = 
       DeleteCases[list, _?(MemberQ[picked, #] &)], picked}]]]
```

An alternative (caveat - not gruelingly tested for correctness, just an idea, very fast):

```
motherPlucker[list_, n_] := 
 With[{o = RandomSample[Ordering[list], n]},
      Join[Extract[list, Transpose[{o}]], Delete[list, Transpose[{o}]]][[Ordering[
      Join[RandomInteger[{1, (Length@list) - n + 1}, n], Range@(Length@list - n)]]]]]
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did, except that mine allows for duplicates to exist in the deck at the beginning, whereas `DeleteCases` will fail there.

Comment: If there's duplicates in the deck, someone's gettin' the short end of mah pistol ;-)

Comment: LOL --------------

Comment: Note: consider using `DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ picked]` -- your code as written with `_?(MemberQ[picked, #] &)` is very slow.  e.g. `pluck[Range@50000, 3000] // place` takes 0.09 seconds here, while `pluckReinsert[Range@50000, 3000]` takes 7.1 seconds.  This change brings it down to 1.7 seconds, and it's probably faster in later versions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: You seriously crack me up (in a good way) - I don't write *everything* with performance in mind (unlike some, hint hint), unless OP implies that's important, I often just vomit out ideas. I figure some kind of take/join/induced ordering (like the multi-insert you did) would be fastest for this by far.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: update, shamelessly borrowed idea, on 200k list with 20k picks, ~1000X faster than pluck/place.

Comment: I accept that some of the things I do will make people laugh at me. :^)  However I certainly *do not* stress performance above all else, and instead I am known for terse style (as you know).  Nevertheless I do try to write fast code when it is not overly involved.  Objectively I think computational complexity is is quite important as code should scale well.  I am well aware that the repeated `Insert` in my code is a bottleneck with very long lists; it seems you found a way around that. :-)

Comment: I'm afraid that your mother algorithm doesn't yield the same probability as the incremental insertion.  Test it yourself.  I hope you are able to fix that as I'll learn something.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: As stated, not rigorously tested, and not nearly interesting enough to spend much more time on. My gut feeling is that neither (mine or your update) is statistically equivalent to a "folded" insert (i.e., as if one took an actual deck and *sequentially* inserted the selection). May ponder it during a smoke, perhaps an interesting chat subject...

Comment: My `place2` *seems* to produce the same distribution over a series of 100,000 runs but I don't have proof.  I look forward to your conclusions as your thinking smokes seem quite effective. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sequentially pluck and reinsert one card at a time so that there are always $N$ possible choices for the pluck operation and $N$ choices for the insert operation you can do the following:

```
list = {card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8};
pluckReinsert[list_, k_] := pluckReinsert[pluckReinsert[list, 1], k - 1];
pluckReinsert[list_, 1] := (Insert[Delete[list, #[[1]]], list[[#[[1]]]], #[[2]]])&[RandomInteger[{1, Length[list]}, 2]];
```

The two random integers I generate with `RandomInteger[{1, Length[list]}, 2]` are the position of the card to be plucked and the position at which it is to be reinserted respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one liner, but reasonably efficient.

```
pluckReinsert[ll_, k_] := Module[
  {n = Length[ll], ksamp, replace, partiall, i = 0, j = 0, 
   replacelist, res},
  ksamp = RandomSample[Range[n], k];
  replace = RandomSample[Range[n], k];
  replacelist = ConstantArray[False, n];
  Do[replacelist[[replace[[j]]]] = True, {j, k}];
  partiall = Delete[ll, Transpose[{ksamp}]];
  ksamp = ll[[ksamp]];
  Table[
   If[TrueQ[replacelist[[m]]], i++; ksamp[[i]], j++; partiall[[j]]]
   , {m, n}]
  ]
```

Example:

```
list = {card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, cardN};
pluckReinsert[list, 4]

(* {card4, card1, card2, card3, card6, card5, card7, card8, cardN} *)
```

Big example:

```
ll = Range[10^6];
Timing[pluckReinsert[ll, 10^2];]
```

(* {3.664000, Null} *)

Here is a versionn using `Compile` that is around 30x faster.

```
pluckReinsertC = Compile[{{ll, _Integer, 1}, {k, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {n = Length[ll], ksamp, replace, partiall, i = 0, j = 0, 
     replacelist, res},
    ksamp = RandomSample[Range[n], k];
    replace = RandomSample[Range[n], k];
    replacelist = ConstantArray[0, n];
    Do[replacelist[[replace[[j]]]] = 1, {j, k}];
    partiall = Delete[ll, Transpose[{ksamp}]];
    ksamp = ll[[ksamp]];
    Table[
     If[replacelist[[m]] == 1, i++; ksamp[[i]], j++; partiall[[j]]]
     , {m, n}]
    ]];
```